# How can I make generating reports more intuitive for a non programmer?

Tags: sql, user-interface, charts, reporting

I made a GUI for generation of SQL, something much similar to MS Access Visual Query Designer, the purpose was to let our Customer Service team make their own reports. But even after designing the whole thing and I can see that they are unsure on how to proceed for generating a new report.

SQL is much intuitive for me after long experience, but things like grouping, aggregate functions, various date/string functions are not easy for a non programmer.

How can I make it easier for a non programmer to build the SQL using a GUI?

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/345j48k.png]

Comment: Which database system are you using? In the case of SQL server, why not use reporting services?

Comment: a regular pc user runs like hell of anything "command" related. they just want to click some buttons and the holly grail to appear. If you made the thing to generate the sql, why don't you go a step further and run the sql and present just the results?

Comment: @ZippyV Mysql, i am not sure what they are, i will check up.

Comment: @VladBalmos yeah results are there and with export as CSV.

Comment: from the image, i guess your problem is that there are to many controls (select fields, checkboxes). I'm not a designer or UI oriented but i would try to minimize the number of inputs, or get help form a designer.

Comment: Aggregate functions I think are not that complicated, people usually understand what MAX, MIN, AVG, mean, at least those functions they have to use. As for aggregating it is often organised automatically in such tools - when user uses aggregate function, the tool implicitly moves all the columns that are not within the aggregate functions into `GROUP BY` clause. That usually is sufficient for regular users needs. As for the other functions, usually some doc with good examples helps.

Comment: Another option would be to make the whole process in a tutorial / wizzard style. First screen -> select the tables, second screen -> select the columns, third screen -> add fileters, ordering, limits, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can apply a simplifying transcription of the SQL. Think something like https://ifttt.com/wtf. This in combination with the visual part might make it easier to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please follw up :
1) combo box for selecting database
2) combo box for selecting  table for selected database
3) One Grid is display columns for selecting table.
4) user select,update column display name, order of display, aggregate of column option, group on column option.
5) finally display result in grid as per selection of column setting.
```

Comment: Its *somewhat* more complex in reality when dealing with a free selection from multiple related tables, 1:n relationships, the subtleties of aggregating & grouping ...

Comment: you have to use systemTable, systemColumns ... and fine where is relationship and getting result..it's something complex but you have to got result as per you and satified to your user.

Comment: I added a pic of what i have currently, The points you mentioned are all covered. Thanks for these. Relations are not taken from database schema, since there are no FK's specified in our schema.